# Unable to automate flutter app using appium because of the incompatibility of flutter_driver_extension

Tags: java, flutter, maven, appium, flutterdriver

I'm following this https://testingbot.com/support/mobile/flutter.html#start reference to setup flutter app for automation using appium with java and maven.
However, when asked with developer, it was found that the flutter_driver_extension is incompatable with the current project.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ng532.png)
What could be possible solution for this? Is there any other alternative for this?
I'm also using browserstack for test execution.

I tried with correct configuration available, but wasn't able to locate the element.

Got this issue with browserstack:
[BROWSERSTACK_START_ERROR] Could not start a session as something went wrong during initialization

Following error in Testng:
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Host info: host: 'Basanta-MacBook-Air.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:8a0:a7b9:8047:2d09%en0'

Comment: It'll be very difficult to ascertain any reason why it might be throwing this error. Could you share any kind of Logs or something?

Comment: Maybe this would help:
 2023-06-12 03:10:11:495 - [FlutterDriver] "ext.flutter.driver" is not found in "extensionRPCs @Tony_Stark